# How to convert time in 24 hr format in iphone?

Tags: iphone, xcode

I have to convert the given time in 24 hr format.But I did not get it.Don't know where I m going wrong.
 If I have TimeStart as 1:15 PM then I should get 13:15 ..

```
Item *item=[sectionItems objectAtIndex:itemId];
 NSLog(@"%@",item.TimeStart);
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"HH:mm a"];
    NSString *formattedDateString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:item.TimeStart];
    NSLog(@"%@",formattedDateString);
```

In the code above I have a Item class and that I have `NSString` *TimeStart;
When I see formattedDateString it is returning null.How can I fix it ?

Comment: What is the definition of an `Item`? What is `TimeStart`?

Comment: what is you TimeStart date format ?? means just post the date which is in TimeStart

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
 Item *item=[sectionItems objectAtIndex:itemId];
  NSLog(@"%@",item.TimeStart);

NSString *str = @"1:45.PM";// put here item.TimeStart

NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"hh:mm.a"];// here give the format which you get in TimeStart

NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString: str];

dateFormatter = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"HH:mm"];

NSString *convertedString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:date];
NSLog(@"Converted String : %@",convertedString);
```

Comment: Its not getting.I have TimeStart as 1:45 PM then I should get as 13:45 and if 11:45 Am then 11:45,if 8:00PM then I should get 20:00 .How can I do it?I tried ur code but still returning null.What elz should I modify ?

Comment: ok just replace this line [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"EEE, d MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss z"]; with [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"hh:mm a"];

Comment: Still it is returning nil.Actually I have item.TimeStart like this 1:45.PM .There is a dot between 45 and PM ..may be dats y it is nil .Should I need to split anything elz?

Answer (score 1):

i just simply setDateFormat like `[formatter setDateFormat:@"HH:mm"];`  Remove `a`

and below caode for checking its time formate is 24 hr or 12

```
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setLocale:[NSLocale currentLocale]];
[formatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterNoStyle];
[formatter setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle];
NSString *dateString = [formatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];
NSRange amRange = [dateString rangeOfString:[formatter AMSymbol]];
NSRange pmRange = [dateString rangeOfString:[formatter PMSymbol]];
BOOL is24h = (amRange.location == NSNotFound && pmRange.location == NSNotFound);
[formatter release];
NSLog(@"%@\n",(is24h ? @"YES" : @"NO"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this to set 24 hr format.

```
[currentDate setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm"];
```

or

```
[formatter setDateFormat:@"HH:mm"];
```

without using formatter

```
NSRange range;
range.location = 2;
range.length = 2;
NSString *dateString=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@:%@",[myString substringToIndex:2],          [myString substringWithRange:range]];
```

This is the code i am using in my project and its working for me

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"HH:mm"];
 NSString *dateString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];

NSLog(@"Current time date:%@", dateString);
```

output:Current time date:14:41

Comment: I tried without using formatter.What I need if it is 1:45. PM I should get 13:45 and if it 11:45 AM I should get 11:45 ..If it is 8:00 PM then it should be 20:00.How can I do it ?